# XSLT ambiguous rule match warning

Tags: xml, xslt

When I run my XSLT stylesheet, I get an ambiguous rule match warning, and one of the templates is not invoked. The template with the **richtext[par]** match criteria is invoked, but the template with the **richtext[table]** match criteria is not. How to invoke both templates and avoid the warning message?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <item name="The Item">
        <richtext>
            <pardef/>
            <par def="20">
                <run>This is the </run>
                <run><font style="underline"/>preamble.</run>
            </par>
            <pardef id="21" list="bullet"/>
            <par def="21">
                <run>This is the </run>
                <run>first bullet.</run>
            </par>
            <par def="20">
                <run/>
            </par>
            <par def="21">
                <run>This is the second </run>
                <run>bullet.</run>
            </par>
            <par def="20">
                <run>This is the </run>
                <run>conclusion.</run>
            </par>
            <table>
                <tablerow>
                    <tablecell>
                        <par def="43"><run>Total Savings ($M)</run></par></tablecell>
                    <tablecell>
                        <pardef/>
                        <par def="50"><run></run></par></tablecell>
                    <tablecell>
                        <par def="44"><run>0.9360</run></par></tablecell>
                    <tablecell>
                        <par def="45"><run>5.0047</run></par></tablecell>
                    <tablecell>
                        <par def="46"><run>8.8080</run></par></tablecell></tablerow></table>

        </richtext>
    </item>
</document>
```

And here is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>
   <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="richtext[table]">
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:for-each select="tablerow">
                <tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="tablecell">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:apply-templates />
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>


                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </table>      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="richtext[par]">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="par[run[normalize-space()]]" group-adjacent="if (@def) then @def else preceding-sibling::par[run[normalize-space()]][@def][1]/@def">
            <xsl:variable name="listType" select="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::pardef]/@list" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$listType = 'bullet'">    
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="list"/>
                    </ul>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$listType = 'ordered'">    
                    <ol>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"  mode="list"/>
                    </ol>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="para" />   
                </xsl:otherwise>     
            </xsl:choose>   
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="par" mode="list">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="run" />
        </li>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par" mode="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="run" />
        </p>  
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="run">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="font[@style = 'underline']">
                <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()" separator=""/>
                </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()" separator=""/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please have a look at your template `richtext[table]`. Your context-node is "richtext" but you create an element "table". So you replace the `richtext` with table! [the for-each runs into nothing, cause the xpath doesnt match on nodes]. Maybe its solved via changing to "richtext/table"?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current code assumes a `richtext` can either have `par` elements, or `table`, or not both. In the case where it has both, both templates match with equal priority, which is considered an error (XSLT may flag the error, or pick the last template).

One way to have to give them both `mode` attributes, but have a single template matching `richtext` that them applies the relevant templates based on whether `table` or `par` (or both) are present:

```
<xsl:template match="richtext">
    <xsl:if test="par">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="par" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="table">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="table" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="richtext" mode="par">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="par" ...>
      <!-- Current code -->
   </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="richtext" mode="table">
   <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="table/tablerow">
            <!-- Current code -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could change your template that currently matches `richtext[table]` to match table instead, then you can do something like this

```
<xsl:template match="richtext[par]">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="par" ...>
         <!-- Current code -->
     </xsl:for-each-group>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="table" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="richtext/table">
   <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="tablerow">
            <!-- Current code -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

In the case of `richtext` not having a `par` then XSLT's built-in templates will apply, and these will select the `table` element for you.

Also note that, because you are positioned on a `table` element, you have to adjust the inner `xsl:for-each` to just select `tablerow` instead.

In fact, you could do something like this too:

```
<xsl:template match="richtext">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="par" ...>
         <!-- Current code -->
     </xsl:for-each-group>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="table" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="richtext/table">
   <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="tablerow">
            <!-- Current code -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

So, in the case of no `par` the `xsl:for-each-group` will do nothing anyway.

Comment: I tried both options and the TABLE template is now invoked, but it's creating an empty table. Is that because each table cell has a PAR element inside it?

Comment: Depending on which option you used (I actually gave three option ;) ), you might have to adjust the select clause on `xsl:for-each` depending on whether you are positioned on a `richtext` or a `table` element. I've amended my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks so much! :)